# Do we need to destroy a CDI bean obtained programmatically?

Tags: java, cdi, java-ee-7

I have obtained a CDI bean which was obtained programatically using the following code:

```
MyBean bean = CDI.current().select(MyBean.class, qualifier).get();
```

Once I am done, do I need to destroy this bean using

```
CDI.current().destroy (bean);
```

Or does the bean inherit the scope from my class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or does the bean inherit the scope from my class?

Definitely no. It will have whatever scope you gave to `MyBean`.

> do I need to destroy this bean

If your bean is normal scoped you don't need to do that. If, however, it is so called pseudo-scope, you might need to destroy it.
For the record, normal scoped are all basic CDI scopes **except for** `@Dependent`.

The reason is that `@Dependent` lifecycle (so destroy as well) is bound to a bean where you inject it. But you didn't really inject it, instead you did programmatic lookup. Therefore, it isn't bound to any other bean and you should destroy it.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful.